# Tomato firmware with separate DCHP server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, dhcp, tomato

I've got a Tomato router which works wonderfully, but I've also got a Windows server that I would like to use as the DHCP server instead of the Tomato router.

I know that I can configure each client to use the server for DHCP manually, but I'd rather configure it so any client that connects gets an IP automatically from the server. The server is already configured correctly, I just don't know how to point the clients to it with the router.

Here's how I would like to have it set up:

**Tomato Router**: 192.168.1.1 (Static)
**DHCP Server**: 192.168.1.50 (Static)
**DHCP Server's Scope**: 192.168.1.2-49

I've researched this but so far all I've found is the WINS server setting, but that doesn't seem to work. How I configure the router to point to the server for DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have to turn off the DHCP server in Tomato and turn it on on your Windows Server.  You don't have to "point" anything at it.  The way [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Operation) works, is it sends a UDP packet to the broadcast address for the subnet, so as long as the server and clients are on the same subnet it should "just work."